# Class.this and this

Tags: android, context

В чем разница между

```
StartScreen.this
```

и

```
this
```

И почему, например, при создании Toast таким образом все работает

```
Toast.makeText(StartScreen.this,"1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

а создавая так, нет

```
Toast.makeText(this,"1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Разница в области видимости. Вполне вероятно, что там, где вы создаёте Toast, this указывает не на StartScreen.

Comment: Понял. Делал это в Runnable, из-за этого. Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все зависит в каком месте вы создаете `Toast`.
Если создавать `Toast` так:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

То в этом случае `this` будет указывать на анонимный класс, а не на `StartScreen`.

Для того, чтобы указать на внешний класс (в вашем случае на StartScreen), то надо писать `StartScreen.this`.