# Intent android studio

Tags: android

Когда мы хотим открыть одну активность из другой, то используем интент с двумя параметрами

new Intent(Context packageContext, Activity.class). Что обозначает первый параметр? В интернете пишут про то что это объект Context, но я не понимаю как это работает, а именно что происходит при такой строчке кода:

Class.this

что возвращает слово this. Я знаю что когда мы вызываем метод на каком-нибудь объекте, например:

obj.showInfo, то слово this будет содержать ссылку на этот объект obj, но что происходит при Class.this?

Comment: Тут про `this`: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/642404/11515, и про контекст: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/643251/11515

Comment: Если this вас интересует, как заменитель класса Context при вызове интента, то дело тут в том, что если вызов осуществляется из класса Activity, мы можем указать его в качестве контекста (написать this, то есть использовать тот класс в котором вы находитесь), так как активити - наследник класса Context и содержит в себе все его свойства, методы и параметры. При вызове из другого класса (например, адаптера) этот номер уже не пройдет.