# Что означает Class.this

Tags: java, android

Я знаю два случая когда используется ключевое слово this:

1. когда вызываем нестатический метод на каком-нибудь объекте, то this неявно передается в параметр этого метода и возвращает ссылку на этот объект;
2. когда мы хотим вызвать один конструктор из другого, здесь this тоже является ссылкой на объект который инициализируется в конструкторе;

Получается, что this - это ссылка на объект. Тогда у меня возникает вопрос, что означает эта запись:

Class.this

Что здесь может возвращать this, если в классе я не создавал никаких объектов. Чем здесь является this?

Comment: Можно же посмотреть дебагером/принтом.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1258341/177345 - это один и тот же вопрос? Если да, то не нужно создавать новые дубликаты, делайте уточнения в уже заданном (кнопка "править" под вопросом)

Answer (score 4):

Записи типа `Class.this` используются во вложенных или анонимных классах, когда из них нам нужно сослаться на объект включающего их класса. **Class** - имя внешнего (включающего) сласса, **this** - ссылка на экземпляр внешнего (включающего) класса. Если вы вложенном классе или анонимном классе обратитесь, просто по **this**, то вы сошлётесь на текущий объект этого вложенного или анонимного класса, а не на объект внешнего.

Comment: Да, это я уже выяснил из просторов инета, но я не понимаю на какой объект мы ссылаемся при такой записи, если в своем классе я не создавал никакого объекта, например когда в своем классе(Info) я создаю объект Intent и в первый параметр конструктора я пишу Info.this. Так на какой объект я ссылаюсь если объектов в классе Info я не создавал?

Comment: @Михаил Вы имеете в виду в первый параметр конструктора объекта Intent? Тогда так: На этапе выполнения, во время создания объекта класса Info в нём будет создан объект класса Intent и в качестве аргумента в конструктор этого объекта (Intent) будет передан сам объект Info, то есть текущий объект класса Info, **но в такой ситуации вы можете использовать просто - this**. Использование `Info.this` в этом случае - это просто для удобочитаемости, этого можно было и не писать

Comment: @Михаил если же вы **не** получаете объект Intent в определении класса Info, а **определяете** класс Intent, как вложенный в класс Info, то ответ дан ранее.

Answer (score 2):

Это контекст текущего объекта этого класса, т.е.:

```
package com.lampa;

public class Main {
    public Main() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                this.test(); // ошибка, т.к. this это Runnable
                Main.this.test();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void test() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```